# IIFE singleton global undefined unless called as window.XYZ = IIFE()

Tags: javascript

Why does this function run and not initialize global `XYZ` with the return value?

```
"use strict";
XYZ = (function(){
    var obj = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3};
    console.log("about to return:");
    console.log(obj);
    return obj;
    })();
 console.log(XYZ); // shows undefined
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t56awez/10/)

What seems odd is that the first two console.log return sensible output, and then Chrome throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: XYZ is not defined`

When using `window.XYZ` explicitly, this works fine:

```
"use strict";
window.XYZ = (function(){
    var obj = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3};
    console.log("about to return:");
    console.log(obj);
    return obj;
    })();
 console.log(XYZ); // shows a:1, b:2, c:3
```

Comment: First code snippet works for me when executed in console

Comment: Probably because "use strict'; does nothing except in particular circumstances (e.g. first line of a file or scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will work if `"use strict;"` is removed.  But don't do that -- keep reading.

Strict mode prevents `XYZ = ...` from becoming a new global variable.

[John Resig explains in his overview of strict mode](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/):

> An attempt to assign `foo = "bar";` where `foo` hasn’t been defined will
>   fail. Previously it would assign the value to the foo property of the
>   global object (e.g. `window.foo`), now it just throws an exception. This
>   is definitely going to catch some annoying bugs.

The code with `window.XYZ = IIFE()` works in strict mode because here the assignment is to a property of an existing object, `window`.

Using `window.XYZ` might be "good enough" for many applications, but you may encounter a platform (such as Meteor) where using `window.XYZ` "short circuits" dependency management in the package manager.  In such a case, strict mode can be enabed inside the IIFE but not at the page level.

To use strict mode with a singleton IIFE assigned to a new global, only turn on strict mode inside the IIFE on its first line.

```js
XYZ = (function() {
  "use strict";
  var obj = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3
  };
  console.log("about to return:");
  console.log(obj);
  return obj;
})();
console.log(XYZ);
```

**Warning: "use strict;" as the 2nd line does not enable strict mode:**

Don't do this:

```
XYZ = 0;
"use strict";
XYZ = ...
```

You can test whether strict mode is enabled by looking at `this` inside a function where `this` is not explicitly set.  When strict mode is true, `this` will be `null` when unset, but when strict mode is false, `this` will be `window`.

See also:  [What does "use strict" do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it)

Comment: Putting `var` before `XYZ` solves the problem, you can add this in answer. Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/wr08jrh2/1/) :)

Comment: `var XYZ` is not global.  This is for library code that is defined in one js file to run in other js files.

Comment: An option could be, setting the value in global scope from inside the IIFE, `window.xyz = obj;` and not returning anything. Then you can remove `XYZ = `. The error will be solved.

Comment: Yes, but MeteorJS, which is one of the consumers of this code, discourages use of `window` to create globals in modules, because this messes up their code-modifying dependency handling is `package.use()`.  The fact that `window.XYZ` works is mentioned in the quesiton.